# Using arrays with a for loop in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am using C and I have an array `t[]`

I wrote a `for` loop but the answer is wrong.

Please help me catch the error. My code is:

```
for(j = 0; j < tags; j++)
{
    for(k = j; k < nb_of_subscribers*tags; k = k+tags)
    {
        avr[j] = (float)(avr[j]+t[k]);
    }
    printf("avr[j]:%f", avr[j]);
}
```

Actually , the values of t[] are read incorrectly in the for loop i don't know why . If i use a for loop only to printf the values of the array t the response is correct otherwise(in the for loop)it is incorrect

Thank you.

Comment: What is your code intended to do? What inputs do you give it, what result do you expect to see, and what do you actually see?

Comment: The answer is 42, so any other answer is indeed wrong.

Comment: t[k]:0.000000 t[k]:0.000000 t[k]:1.000000 t[k]:0.200000 t[k]:0.333333 ........the result is :avr[j]:-12516448 which is wrong i actually want the sum of the values of t

Comment: Could you pls your completely. and precisely what you intended to do?

Comment: And what value does avr[j] contain at the begining?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, he means to say that t is striped across multiple subscribers, so `t[] = { subscriber #1 (tag 1), subscriber #2 (tag 1), subscriber #n (tag1), subscriber #1 (tag 2), subscriber #2 (tag 2, subscriber #n (tag2), ...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `avr[j]` to 0 before starting your iterative sum:

```
for(j = 0; j < tags; j++)
{
    avr[j] = 0; // <-----
    for(k = j; k < nb_of_subscribers*tags; k = k+tags)
    {
        avr[j] = (float)(avr[j]+t[k]);
    }
    printf("avr[j]:%f", avr[j]);
}
```

Comment: Actually , the values of t[] are read incorrectly in the for loop i don't know why . If i use a for loop only to printf the values of the array t the response is correct otherwise(in the for loop)it is incorrect

Comment: @holy, there is nothing in this piece of code that would give you wrong values. Can you print the values of `k` exactly before this array and inside the array and compare the results? Note that printing value of `t` one by one gives you data subscriber-by-subscriber, while inside this loop you get them tag-by-tag.

Comment: t[k]:0.000000 t[k]:0.000000 t[k]:1.000000 t[k]:0.200000 t[k]:0.333333 ........the result is :avr[j]:-12516448 which is wrong i actually want the sum of the values of t

Comment: Did you set `avr[j] = 0` in the beginning like I said? Also, what is the type of `avr`?

Comment: yes.The type of avr is a float like t

Comment: Why? What if `nb_of_subscribers*tags` evaluates to zero? Then your code overwrites data it shouldn't be touching. It is probably better to use a temp variable in the loop, then write the result of that to avr[j] when the loop is finished.

Comment: @lundin if `nb_of_subscribers*tags` is zero, clearly the average of data (therefore `avr`) is zero, don't you think? So everything should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

So I assume that t is an array of size nb_of_subscribers*tags and avr is an array of size tags.

If I'm not mistaken, what you intend to do is the following:

```
for(int j = 0; j < tags; j++)
{
    for(int k = 0; k < nb_of_subscribers; k++)
    {
        avr[j] += (float)(t[j + k*tags]);
    }
    printf("avr[j]:%f", avr[j]);
}
```

Which is to say, assuming tags were 2 and nb_of_subscribers were 3, with the array t[6] = {0, 5, 1, 6, 2, 7}, then array avr[2] would be {3, 18}.  Am I correct in that this is what you wanted to do?